# Biometric Residence Permit (BRP) expiry February 2024 including dependents

Tags: united-kingdom, resident-permit

My family's BRP (me, spouse, child) will expire on February 17, 2024. We are intending to have a short holiday to Prague on December 10-14, 2023. Are we still allowed to have that short holiday and return back to UK using the same BRP? And will start renewing when we come back? technically, the BRP is expiry 2 months before.

Comment: What is a BRP ?

Comment: Is your visa due to expire too? https://www.gov.uk/biometric-residence-permits/replace-expired-brp